# What causes my Macbook to spontaneously shut down?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, catalina, graphics

Out of the blue today, my Macbook Pro 2015 15", running macOS Catalina 10.15.2, shut down while I was using it.

Since then, for the past half hour or so, I haven't been able to keep it on for longer than a minute or so. It either spontaneously shuts down, requiring me to manually turn it back on, or it spontaneously restarts. Now (a day later) it only spontaneously shuts down. It doesn't restart itself.

This happens when it is plugged into the charger and when it is simply running on battery. This also happens while only headphones are connected to the MacBook, or while no peripherals are connected.

Apple Diagnostics shows "No issues found."

I have tried resetting SMC and NVRAM.

Additionally, when starting up I notice weird graphical glitches, for example a white bar sometimes appears on the left side of the screen, or the apple logo repeatedly resizes itself, or a regular pattern of white rectangles appears across the whole screen.

I got a picture of that:

[image]

This flashes onto the screen after the first apple logo appears.

The Macbook does not spontaneously shut down or restart when I boot it into Recovery Mode or Safe Mode.

However, there are also graphical glitches in both of these modes; look at the terminal tabs in Recovery Mode:

[image]
[image]

Moving the mouse cursor over the tabs causes them to scintillate randomly, rectangular monochrome patterns. and glitches.

Exactly the same graphical glitch happens to Finder tabs in Safe Mode.

Why does my Macbook restart like that after I've booted it normally? How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I assume you have run your MBP on Safe Mode too? Do you still get the same issue after rebooting back from Safe Mode?

Comment: Great :). I will post the answer relevant to it so other people can get the solution if they faced a similar issue. Now, once you are back in your normal mode, if it doesn't reboot then we are in good shape but if it appears, then let me know.

Comment: But you cannot stay in safe mode forever, shouldn't you find out the third party kernel that causes the issue? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310758/313842

Comment: @ankii, Third party kernel extensions are not loaded when booted to macOS Recovery, so I doubt that has anything to do with the issue. Probably a hardware issue.

Comment: @theonlygusti: just trying to followup so I can give you the solution that I know. After you came back from Safe boot mode, does your computer still reboot ? or it stopped. If not, as suggest by Ankii, you have to look for 3rd p kexts which is creating issue.

Comment: Are there any crash reports?

Comment: @Udhy problem started happening again. Maybe the Safe Mode boot temporarily fixed it? For almost an hour (although the first normal boot after safe mode also crashed)

Comment: @user3439894 there are no crash reports, or errors/notifications etc. of any kind

Comment: Are the fans working? How hot is the MBP getting. A spontaneous full shutdown can be hardware related, and in light of the fact there are no reports, I'd be looking in that direction.

Comment: @user3439894 is it possible for a hardware problem to be the cause? Why doesn't it happen when I boot into recovery or safe mode?

Comment: I'd be looking for a heat problem. Get a fan on your machine. Get some space between you mac and the table top. There are some third party heat monitors. Get. fyi: In safe mode, the video chip isn't being used.

Comment: RE: " I just noticed though that my click feels extremely different to how it should: feels jarring sharp and makes a really loud harsh clicking noise even though I have silent clicking enabled (used to be really soft)" ... If you are referring to the built-in Trackpad, then it could be a battery swelling issue.

Comment: @user3439894 the fans work. Idk how hot the Macbook is when it crashes (how do I find that out?) I noticed just now my trackpad click feels inconsistent

Comment: I've seen similar behavior, spontaneous shutdown/reboots and graphic glitches on a MBP with a bad battery. If you take the edge of a ruler to especially the bottom of the case and it doesn't make flat contact from edge to edge and in between, or it can rock back and forth then the battery is most definitely swelling and putting undue pressure where is shouldn't have pressure being applied. This can cause all sorts of issues. Have a look at https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall to see if you qualify, if the battery is indeed swelling.

Comment: @user3439894 do you know why it doesn't happen in recovery or safe boot mode? i would expect a battery problem to cause issues there too

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for all the help. Indeed there are small gaps under a flat edge when I run it along the bottom case, so the bottom case is slightly concave. My bottom case has looked a bit beaten up since quite a long time, has a couple dents and scratches, so I wouldn't know whether a swelling battery causes the uneven surface. When I've saved all my important data I'll just try a fresh OS install.

Answer (score 1):

Your symptoms are either a bad driver / os for the video subsystem or a hardware failure.

In case of hardware, safe mode will often run since it doesn’t ask as much of the video system which runs in a fail safe / basic mode. Also, it can slow down the rendering so you can easily see the failure modes or grab a screen shot.

Before paying for a repair, consider charting how often this happens and back up / erase install to be [sure this is the hardware / vram failing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100971/5472).

As to the shutdown, unless there’s a severe failure, you should get. A kernel panic, but if the logs show no events and no panics, then that’s another reason to suspect hardware failure.

Since your mac won’t run more than 5 minutes in normal mode, why not back it up in safe mode and try an erase install. If your Mac can’t reinstall itself, then you know it’s repair time. If it can, you’ll be back in business

Comment: There are no relevant files in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. Is there another log location I should have checked?

Comment: I look at the whole console - `/var/log/system.log` will help you pinpoint the boot time as will `last reboot` @theonlygusti

Comment: I find it hard to read the `/var/log/system.log` file, I don't know what everything means and don't know what to look for. At a glance however, I don't see anything that stands out to me as an error. I read the lines near the timestamps returned by `last reboot`

Comment: How are you reading the file if it shuts down in a minute?

Comment: I am just using Safe Boot mode. Everything (that I have tried so far, except audio output) works fine in Safe Boot mode.

Comment: Time to back up and erase install, then @theonlygusti - bummer if it’s hardware.
 But at least you’ll know

Comment: Yeah I hope  won't be. Is the best way to do that using recovery mode "reinstall macOS" or however the option is called?